# Django Product Gallery

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I create shop for train Django. I have problem with product gallery. 
I want create somethink like this 
[image]

And in do it.

```
<img src="{{ product.image_url|default_if_none:'#' }}">
```

but I have only one image

How can I add "product gallery" ?

I must add ne field on Product models to storage photos ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because setting up commercial hosting config is not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the choices is to create one more model for example `ProductGallery` with `ForeignKey` on your product. For example, if your product model called `Product`, then you should create:

```
class ProductGallery(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(u'Изображения', upload_to='countries/images/', blank=True)
  countries = models.ForeignKey('Product', blank=True, null=True)
```

to add images in product admin you have to add this code in `admin.py`:

```
class ImagesInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = ProductGallery

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [
    ImagesInline,
  ]
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Hope its helps you